# what's meaning of "global::" in gtk programming

Tags: mono, gtk#

I  always found the code like "this.fixed1 = new global::Gtk.Fixed();" i don't know what the "global::" useful is.
Is there anybody could explain for this?

Answer (score 1):

It is used to disambiguate symbols--it just means that the `Gtk` you're referring to is at the top level.  Without it if you had a nested `Gtk` symbol in your code (e.g., a `Foo.Gtk` namespace) and had a `using Foo` statement somewhere the compiler would have no way of knowing what you meant when you type `Gtk`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713620.aspx if you want more info.